# How to specify field size for columns in accdb file using R?

Tags: r, ms-access

I'm trying to specify field sizes in accdb file using R to avoid every time doing it manually I open newly generated access file. I have empty accdb file where data frame is pasted.

```
library("RODBC")
# Stores data types of columns for table resp
ColDataTypes <- list(RESP_CODE = "VARCHAR(8)", koef = "DOUBLE", outl = "VARCHAR(1)")
# Opens connection to file
con <- odbcConnectAccess2007(paste0(PathReport,"1apgr_", NYear, "m", CMonth,"_svari.accdb"))
# Saves resp table
sqlSave(con, DataDelivery,
        tablename = "resp",
        safer = FALSE, varTypes = ColDataTypes, rownames = FALSE)
```

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by altering columns in MS-Access with query that was sent to it by R.

```
library("RODBC")
# Stores data types of columns for table resp
ColDataTypes <- list(RESP_CODE = "VARCHAR(8)", koef = "DOUBLE", outl = "VARCHAR(1)")
# Opens connection to file
con <- odbcConnectAccess2007(paste0(PathReport,"1apgr_", NYear, "m", CMonth,"_svari.accdb"))
# Saves resp table
sqlSave(con, DataDelivery,
        tablename = "resp",
        safer = FALSE, varTypes = ColDataTypes, rownames = FALSE)
#Changes data type for column
sqlQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE resp ALTER COLUMN RESP_CODE VARCHAR(8);")
#Changes data type for column
sqlQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE resp ALTER COLUMN koef DOUBLE;")
#Changes data type for column
sqlQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE resp ALTER COLUMN outl VARCHAR(1);")
```

It is useful to create table with desired datatypes in MS-Access and then to get datatypes from it from R to know what to write in queries, where 'resp' is table name.

```
#Finding datatypes of columns for single table in access file 
 con <- odbcConnectAccess2007("T:/svari.accdb")
 sqlColumns(con, 'resp', errors = FALSE, as.is = TRUE,
            special = FALSE, catalog = NULL, schema = NULL,
            literal = FALSE)
 odbcClose(con)
```